# Grafana: Math calculation between two panels

Tags: prometheus, grafana, performance-testing, influxdb, grafana-variable

I am creating a real time dashboard from performance testing perspective that would fetch data from InfluxDB (mostly client side) and Prometheus (server side). It will have below panels (will look fancier in Grafana, of course).

| Metric | Value | Weightage | Score | Final Score | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Error Percent | 8.9% | 1 | 2 | 2 | Score 1:<5%, Score 2:5-10%,Score 3 >10% |
| Response Time | 2.5 s | 3 | 1 | 3 | Score 1:<3s, Score 2:3-6s,Score 3 >6s |

- Metric: Text Panel(Could be markdown or HTML)
- Value: Stat Panel (Will be calculated using queries)
- Weightage: Text Panel (User driven and it will have **variable** dropdown). Text panel will simply display the variable value selected by the user
- Score: Stat Panel (It will be **value mapping** of metric as per description and will point to value panel)
- Final Score: This will be the multiplication of weightage and score and this is my pain point at the moment.

I am struggling to do multiplication of a Grafana variable (as text) and the value mapping that is done on the query result.

Is there a way we can do math operations on **Weightage** and **Score**. Tried my hands with transform but no luck. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Adding Queries and data returned from Prometheus and InfluxDB.

Below InfluxDB query returns Error% (Example: 4.56%)

```sql
SELECT sum("error") / sum("all") 
FROM (
    SELECT sum("count") AS "all" 
    FROM "$measurement_name" 
    WHERE "transaction" = 'all'
    AND "application"=~ /^$application$/ 
    AND $timeFilter 
    GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
), (
    SELECT sum("countError") AS "error" 
    FROM "$measurement_name" 
    WHERE "transaction" = 'all' 
    AND "application" =~ /^$application$/ 
    AND $timeFilter 
    GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
)
```

Below Prometheus query will return CPU Utilization % (For example- 52.5%)

```
sum(node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate{cluster="$cluster", namespace="$namespace"}) / sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests{job="kube-state-metrics", cluster="$cluster", namespace="$namespace", resource="cpu"})
```

Comment: Please, [edit] question and add example of data returned from prometheus and influx right now and queries used for this (as text!)

Comment: @markalex I have made the edit as requested.